# How to configure client and server to make client auto refresh in spring cloud confi

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have created the demo for client as well as server using spring cloud config documentation. I am using git properties file for external configuration. If I made any change in external configuration file and refresh the client then its working fine. But I don't want to refresh each and every time. I want to make my client in such a way that it will auto refresh.

I go through spring documentation and I think we can do it with following way.

1. With help of Redis
2. Spring cloud bus

Which one is right way to do it?

Currently I am trying first one with https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/configserver/ but it did't work.

So any one please explain me how to configure client and server so that we don't need to refresh client?

Should I moved with spring cloud bus?

Answer (score 6):

There is no "right" way. To monitor changes in the config server you need the `spring-cloud-config-monitor` (or that could be used in a standalone app). It uses Spring Cloud Bus to broadcast the change events, but you have to choose a transport (so Redis is one valid choice).

You also need to listen for the changes on your client, so add the `spring-cloud-starter-bus-redis` (or `amqp` or `kafka` etc. if you use a different transport on the server).

The sample you linked to is currently hooked up to monitor changes and propagate them via Spring Cloud Bus over Redis (the dependencies `spring-cloud-config-monitor` and `spring-cloud-starter-stream-redis` switch this on):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-monitor</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

To receive notifications from github though, you need to register your application URL with your github repository. The sample doesn't have a URL, so it isn't registered. If you change it to use a file-based repository (e.g. a local git repo) then it will monitor the files and won't need a hook.